# II7 Rewrite Issues - excluding pages

Tags: url, iis-7, url-rewriting

> Hey all, I've got a question about
>   IIS7 rewrite.
>
> I'm wondering if there is a way to set
>   conditions for re writing urls. I'm
>   wanting to rewrite:
>
> > http://www.domain.com/user.aspx?id=username
>
> to become
>
> http://www.domain.com/username/
>
> I also have
>
> > http://www.domain.com/article.aspx
> >     http://www.domain.com/login.aspx
>
> and I want those to become
>
> > http://www.domain.com/article/
> >     http://www.domain.com/login/
>
> The issue I'm having is that if I set
>   up the rewrites for username the
>   rewrites for article and login break.
>
> I need to somehow exclude those from
>   the username rewriting so that they
>   can be handled on their own.
>
> Here is my current code, im rewriting
>   the usernames to /user/username at the
>   moment:
>
> ```
> <rewrite>
>   <rules>
>     <rule name="Rewrite user accounts2">
>       <match url="user/([_0-9a-z-]+)"/>
>       <action type="Rewrite" url="user.aspx?id={R:1}"/>
>     </rule>
>     <rule name="Rewrite user accounts">
>       <match url="user/([_0-9a-z-]+)/"/>
>       <action type="Rewrite" url="user.aspx?id={R:1}"/>
>     </rule>
>   </rules>
> </rewrite>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the article/login rule at the top and add stopProcessing="true" to it then you dont have to use conditions.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Login" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="login/?"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="login.aspx"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Article" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="article/?"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite user accounts2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="user/([_0-9a-z-]+)/?"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="user.aspx?id={R:1}"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

PS. the questionmark makes the preceding character optional.

Comment: Thanks so much Fabian, just one more part to the question.

Say I want to take away /user/ and just make the account domain.com/username/ how do I stop it conflicting with the login/article rewrites?

Matt

Comment: You're quite welcome :).
You can just remove user/ from the match url in the example i wrote.
So when its not login or article it will check "([_0-9a-z-]+)/?" and rewrite accordingly.